# No module named project.spiders.myspider on custom script

Tags: python, scrapy, python-import

I developed a scrapy project with 3 levels of inheritance:

- [root_scrapy]/lib/basedSpider : Which contains all crawling process, loop on xpath, etc..
- [root_scrapy]/lib/myspider : Which contains all xpath to search information & inherit from basedSpider
- [root_scrapy]/spiders/myspider : Which contains multiple spider with only starts_urls/name & inherit from lib/myspider

I want to create a python script to launch all spiders includes on spiders/myspiders to avoid call (or crontab) scrapy crawl name1|name2|name3|etc..

I try [Running multiple spiders in the same process](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html?highlight=process#running-multiple-spiders-in-the-same-process), and many others solutions with "scrapy launch script" google results, but every time I've

```
ImportError: No module named project.project.spiders.myspider
```

or with using sys.path.append on my script

```
ImportError: No module named project.project.lib.myspider
```

And for now I can't launch multiple spiders from python script..

Is it possible to create a global spider which calls all other spiders, with that I can launch it with **scrapy crawl myGlobalSpider**

Comment: Can you get the full stack trace from your error? I am wondering where exactly the error is coming from. In my opinion the error should happen in your own script which does the calls to `process.crawl(...)`, then it should be more a question about python folder structures (maybe you are just lacking `__init__.py` files). The alternative would be that you need a custom spider loader or set the path for the default spider loader, but I think the spider loader should not be used when you use the programmatic access.

Comment: It's an import error, not really have full strack trace, it just output line of bad import, and what I write on first message. I've `__init__.py` on all folders. I also try to add all paths to python path, without success.. If I don't find solution, I thinks I'll change myspiders to include all starts_urls, and parse it on basedSpider. Hope it'll works...